# Virtualbox's version number doesn't change after update (OSX)

Tags: macos, virtualbox

If I check for updates I get this message

`A new version of VirtualBox has been released! Version 3.2.10 is available at virtualbox.org. You can download this version using the link:
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.2.10/VirtualBox-3.2.10-66523-OSX.dmg`

I installed the downloaded file a few times but the version is still 3.2.8. Any idea what to do? I do not want to uninstall as I might lose all the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download actually contains version 3.2.10, I checked. So there might be something wrong with the installer.

Did you move the VirtualBox files around (so that you have two copies now, the old one and the new one)? Maybe change permissions on the previously installed files?

---

Regarding Uninstall: You can look at `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool` yourself, it doesn't remove your preferences. It only removes:

1. Package Receipts (i.e. installer logs)
2. Kernel extensions
3. Binaries in `/usr/bin`
4. Startup Items
5. The actual application bundle in `/Applications`.
6. The VirtualBox Python API/Library

So you should be able to uninstall and reinstall without too much risk.

Comment: cool, I uninstalled and installed VB again and the version number is fine. Thank you.